# Android OnActivityResult passing data to another form and getting array result from it

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I want to send some Data to another activity say SecondActivity and then getting Array data from That SecondActivity to Main activity using OnActivityResult

This is a app like when i press upload button i already have path i want to send that path to another activity and then getting the result in array from another activity to same mainactivity and then want to view that array in textview

CSVUpload

```
public class CSVUploader extends Activity {
    Button btnUpload;
    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtMessageName;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String FullPath = extras.getString("FullPath");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{
    File csvfile = new File(FullPath);
    FileInputStream csvStream = new FileInputStream(csvfile);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvStream));
    String line;
    String[] name = null;
    String[] number = null;
    int iCount=0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                name[iCount] = RowData[0];
                number[iCount] = RowData[1];
                iCount++;
/*                  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(key, value);
                values.put(CsvProvider.NUMBER, number);
                values.put("status",status);
                getContentResolver().insert(CsvProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
*/              }
            in.close();
            Bundle b =new Bundle();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            b.putStringArray("name", name);
            b.putStringArray("number", number);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

FirstActivity

```
  public void uploadfile(View view){
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile);
        Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, FullPath, 2000).show();
        if(FullPath != null)
        {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CSVUploader.class);
        intent1.putExtra("FullPath", FullPath);
        startActivityForResult(intent1, 2);     
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "No File Selected", 2000).show();
        }
    }

 // Listen for results.
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                    curPathName = data.getStringExtra("GetPath"); 
                    curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
                    FullPath = curPathName+"/"+curFileName;
                    edittext.setText(curFileName);
    /*              Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, resId, duration);*/
                }
             }

        if (requestCode==2){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
                String[] name=b.getStringArray("name");
                String[] number=b.getStringArray("number");
                String[] status;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check this out http://techblogon.com/android-start-activity-for-result-example/. That is `requestCode`, pass an integer value.

Comment: Hey can u look at the code now so you will get it exactly what i want

Comment: Coz i want to retrive an array its a CSV uploader kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code. I am not sure this will work properly

**MainActivity.java**

public void uploadfile(View view){

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CSVUploader.class);       
intent1.putExtra("FullPath", FullPath);         
startActivity(intent1);
```

}

Replace your code likewise

**CSVUploader.java**

```
   Bundle b=new Bundle();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        b.putStringArray("name",name); 
        b.putStringArray("number",number) 
         i.putExtras(b);
         startActivity(i);
```

You can retrive it in MainActivity.java as

```
 Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String[] name=b.getStringArray("name");
  String[] number=b.getStringArray("number");
```

Comment: Cant use this as putExtra is for a single string and not an array

Comment: Actually I have 2 array to retrive

Comment: what are the Errors you get while running

Comment: There are no runtime error it showing me replace to some other methods

Comment: I have made few changes ...Try to use that changes in your code

Comment: Cant use putStringArrayListExtra itshowing me suggetion for putStringArrayList

Comment: `if(!path.equals(""))
{


  Bundle b=new Bundle();
  b.putStringArray("array", Arrayname);
  Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
  i.putExtras(b);
   startActivity(i);

}  `
I dont get why are u using this code

Comment: i just used it before got your complete code. Now i have made correction in your code.

Comment: its not allowing me to use `putStringArrayListExtra` it showing suggestion `putStringArrayList`

Comment: And its onActivityResult not startActivity

Comment: i dont use here startActivityForResult....then why do you bother about onActivityResult

Comment: Cause I am using startActivityForResult :)  I want to view that array in the same activity

Comment: Due to low rep i need to edit my answer please check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the retrieving code into onCreate instead of where you have it now.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
      String FullPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("FullPath");
```

By the way why you want to use another activity to do the task. Why dont you do it in the same activity.

Comment: Yes you are right but i just want a simple view for it let me try your suggestion